# common js require vs. ES2015 import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In a lot of code written for node.js you can see something like

```
var debug = require('debug')('myserver:sub-bit');
```

The question I have, is how do I do this with import? The following does not seem to work.

```
var debug = (import d from 'debug')('myserver:sub-bit');
```

Nor have I found any other working short variations. The long approach, of course, does

```
import debugLib as 'debug';
var debug = debugLib('myserver:sub-bit');
```

But I just wanted an approach that didn't need to be broken out into two statements.

Comment: does `import {foo, bar} from "my-module";` fit the bill? [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation, after trying to be purist about ES6, is to use `import` if you're importing an ES6 module, and `require()` if you want to use an ES5 module. This also makes it clear from reading your code what you can expect from the external module.